# Juniper with multiple DHCP pool connected to Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, juniper, srx

Newbie question:

In our law office we have the following setup: Juniper SRX connected to Cisco L3 switch via trunk port.

Cisco switch has:

VLAN 5 range:   10.4.0.10 - 250 /24
VLAN 6 range:   10.5.0.10 - 250 /24

I want to setup DHCP pool on the Juniper side while keeping those VLANs in mind:

set system services dhcp pool 10.4.0.0/24 address-range low 10.4.0.10
set system services dhcp pool 10.4.0.0/24 address-range high 10.4.0.250
set system services dhcp pool 10.5.0.0/24 address-range low 10.5.0.10
set system services dhcp pool 10.5.0.0/24 address-range high 10.5.0.250

What would be the IP address of the router assigned to clients for the DHCP pool?

set system services dhcp pool 10.4.0.0/24 router ???
set system services dhcp pool 10.5.0.0/24 router ???

Am I even on the right track?
Any other suggestions or something to keep in mind?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right page. You need to start by creating the vlans and setting the interfaces on the SRX. The router will be the IP of the Juniper on that vlan.

## Create Vlans

set vlans marketing vlan-id 5
set vlans finance vlan-id 6
commit

## Decide which interfaces to use

[edit interfaces ge-0/0/3]
set unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members marketing finance  (you might need to separate marketing and finance into two commands or use a comma between. Not sure....)
commit

## Create layer3 interface for each vlan

set interface vlan unit 5 family inet address 10.4.0.1/24  (assuming .1 is what you want the SRX to be)
set interface vlan unit 6 family inet address 10.5.0.1/24

## Finish dhcp pool config

set system serivces dhcp pool 10.4.0.0/24 router 10.4.0.1 (assuming this is what you picked above to be the SRX)
set vlan marketing l3-interface vlan.5
set system serivces dhcp pool 10.5.0.0/24 router 10.5.0.1 (assuming this is what you picked above to be the SRX)
set vlan marketing l3-interface vlan.6

more info: http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-dhcp-server-for-multiple-vlans-in-junos/

Comment: Thank you, Paul! Another thing I forgot to mention: I have VLAN 7 setup for trunking on Cisco and the same matching VLAN 7 on Juniper assigned to its trunk port. Anything else I need to consider? From what I understand, I just need to create matching VLANs 5 and 6 on the Juniper's trunk, correct?

Comment: If you mean that the trunk between the switch and the SRX is passing vlan7, yes you need to add vlans 5 and 6 to the trunk on both sides.

Comment: @Mark, Were you able to get it going?

Comment: Sorry, was away for a while (out-of town meeting). So far all looks good and I am accepting your answer, Paul. So when I >> set interface vlan unit 5 family inet address 10.4.0.1/24 << I am assigning this IP address to serve as a gateway for my vlan5, correct? Thanks again.